# Javascript help - disable form button until both "input" and "textarea" are filled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small script disabling a form button until all inputs in my HTML are filled. I would like to also have "textarea" HTML be filled for the form button to be enabled.

In other words, the form button must be enabled if both "input" and "textarea" are filled in, not just "input".

I'm an absolute beginner with JS :(

This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('input').on('keyup', validate);

});


function validate(){

    $("input[class=form-control]").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0)
        {
            $("button[type=disabled-on-empty-form]").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else
        {
            $("button[type=disabled-on-empty-form]").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: HTML does this by default. you the required attribute!

Comment: keyup will not fire if your user uses their mouse to paste in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
  $('.form-control').on('keyup', validate);
});


function validate() {
  let isValid = true;
  $(".form-control").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      isValid = false;
    }
  });
  
  if (isValid) {
    $("button[type=disabled-on-empty-form]").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("button[type=disabled-on-empty-form]").prop("disabled", true);
  }

}
```

Give each control a class of 'form-control'. So all your input and textarea will have this class.
**Note:** Button element type should be either **submit**, **button**, or **reset**. You should add something like id or class to get the button element.

Answer (score 0):

First, add `textarea` to the selector. In addition, use a boolean flag to store if any input was not filled and only disable the button at the end of the loop.

```js
let disable = false;
$("input.form-control, textarea").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val().length) disable = true;
});
$("button[type=disabled-on-empty-form]").prop("disabled", disable);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML has validation built in to prevent the form from being submitted, no JavaScript required. Just add the required attribute.

```css
label {
  display:block;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Foo<input type="text" name "t" required/></label>
  <label>Bar<input type="text" name "t" required/></label>
  <label>Baz<textarea name "ta" required></textarea></label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you want to fix your code, you should only be disabling the form when you find the issue since you have multiple elements. You code is undoing the last check.

```js
function validate(){

const hasEmpty = $("input, textarea").toArray().some(function (elem) {
  return !elem.value.trim().length;
});

$("button").prop( "disabled", hasEmpty );

}

$("form :input").on("input", validate).trigger("input");
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>Foo<input type="text" name "t" /></label>
  <label>Bar<input type="text" name "t" /></label>
  <label>Baz<textarea name "ta" ></textarea></label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```